# How to solve System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe FileNotFoundException Google Protobuf? (Using C++ and C#) In Unity

Tags: c#, c++, unity-game-engine, protocol-buffers

After having changed my C++ code through my previous question, I found myself unable to display the data within Unity. It has a Debug.Log function which should display the 'array' I sent through from C#. Now this issue had evolved into a FileNotFoundException, tying into the currently asked question.

The error is as follows:

```
FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe, Version=4.0.4.1, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies.
Google.Protobuf.CodedInputStream.ReadFloat () (at <817bcbeeba124ec59e5347ee91ea8025>:0)
Sphere.Sphere+Types+Position.MergeFrom (Google.Protobuf.CodedInputStream input) (at Assets/Scripts/Test/Sphere/Sphere.cs:385)
Google.Protobuf.ParsingPrimitivesMessages.ReadRawMessage (Google.Protobuf.ParseContext& ctx, Google.Protobuf.IMessage message) (at <817bcbeeba124ec59e5347ee91ea8025>:0)
Google.Protobuf.ParsingPrimitivesMessages.ReadMessage (Google.Protobuf.ParseContext& ctx, Google.Protobuf.IMessage message) (at <817bcbeeba124ec59e5347ee91ea8025>:0)
Google.Protobuf.CodedInputStream.ReadMessage (Google.Protobuf.IMessage builder) (at <817bcbeeba124ec59e5347ee91ea8025>:0)
Sphere.Sphere.MergeFrom (Google.Protobuf.CodedInputStream input) (at Assets/Scripts/Test/Sphere/Sphere.cs:199)
Google.Protobuf.ParsingPrimitivesMessages.ReadRawMessage (Google.Protobuf.ParseContext& ctx, Google.Protobuf.IMessage message) (at <817bcbeeba124ec59e5347ee91ea8025>:0)
Google.Protobuf.ParsingPrimitivesMessages.ReadMessage (Google.Protobuf.ParseContext& ctx, Google.Protobuf.IMessage message) (at <817bcbeeba124ec59e5347ee91ea8025>:0)
Google.Protobuf.FieldCodec+<>c__DisplayClass32_0`1[T].<ForMessage>b__0 (Google.Protobuf.ParseContext& ctx) (at <817bcbeeba124ec59e5347ee91ea8025>:0)
Google.Protobuf.Collections.RepeatedField`1[T].AddEntriesFrom (Google.Protobuf.ParseContext& ctx, Google.Protobuf.FieldCodec`1[T] codec) (at <817bcbeeba124ec59e5347ee91ea8025>:0)
Google.Protobuf.Collections.RepeatedField`1[T].AddEntriesFrom (Google.Protobuf.CodedInputStream input, Google.Protobuf.FieldCodec`1[T] codec) (at <817bcbeeba124ec59e5347ee91ea8025>:0)
Sphere.Spheres.MergeFrom (Google.Protobuf.CodedInputStream input) (at Assets/Scripts/Test/Sphere/Sphere.cs:704)
Google.Protobuf.MessageExtensions.MergeFrom (Google.Protobuf.IMessage message, System.IO.Stream input, System.Boolean discardUnknownFields, Google.Protobuf.ExtensionRegistry registry) (at <817bcbeeba124ec59e5347ee91ea8025>:0)
Google.Protobuf.MessageParser`1[T].ParseFrom (System.IO.Stream input) (at <817bcbeeba124ec59e5347ee91ea8025>:0)
Sphere_receive.Start () (at Assets/Scripts/Test/Sphere/Sphere_receive.cs:22)
```

**EDITED** The corresponding Sphere.cs block appeared to be to big for the body in its entirety, if you want to look at it please ask.

Now my own C# implementation of the original idea looked something like this:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.IO;
using UnityEngine;
using Sphere;
using Google.Protobuf;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;


public class Sphere_receive : MonoBehaviour
{
    private GameObject blockObj1, blockObj2, blockObj3;    
    private Vector3 position1, scale1, position2, scale2, position3, scale3;
    private Spheres sphereCollection;
    private string String;
    
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {

    using(var input = File.OpenRead("./Assets/Scripts/sphereData.dat"))
    {
        sphereCollection = Spheres.Parser.ParseFrom(input);
    }

 
    Debug.Log(sphereCollection.ToString());

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        
    }
}
```

I dont know exactly whether the fact my Debug.Log not showing could be related to the thrown error, or if my implementation is simply wrong.

Comment: could you add inheritance of `Spheres` and eventually `Sphere` (if it's some kind of collection) ?

Comment: @Selvin yeah so. Sphere is the cs file generated by Protobuf that holds the information about both Sphere and Spheres, there's no further Spheres collection to be added to the inheritance.

Comment: no funky stuff like deriving them from `MonoBehaviour` or any other Unity class ?

Comment: Then the problem maybe (as excpetion stated with `System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe` ... which version you've added ? seems like your protobuf version is using 4.5.3 ... did you add redirecting (fx if you are using newer version in your project)?

Comment: @Selvin I guess it's not out of the question. Another file I generated like 2-3 weeks earlier does not have this issue though. Now it is ofcourse possible that one of either libraries has been updated in the meantime. I just tried reinstalling my Protobuf nuget packages that did not seem to solve it. Now im trying to work out how I can see which version I have for the System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe library to check if it may simply be a version mismatch.

Comment: I figured out apparently System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe.dll v4.5.3 for whatever reason is seen as assembly version 4.0.4.1, when trying to specifically download this version of the library it states that the System.Runtime version is older than v5.0 and that the CompilerServices.Unsafe is incompatible with all frameworks in the project. The latest listed version of System.Runtime in the NuGet gallery is version 4.3.1 however, so that's just great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so, after some very painful experimentation what has appeared to be the proper solution for me here was the following:

1. I looked up [System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe/4.5.3) **v4.5.3** on the NuGet Gallery and dowloaded the package. *(Version 4.5.3 is also assembly version 4.0.4.1)*
2. Changed the downloaded *.nupkg* to a *.zip* *(Don't know if it's a relevant step or not though)*
3. Extracted it and located the *System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe.dll* file within the `lib/netstandard2.0` folder
4. Dragged this .dll into the project folder

Seems the solution appeared a lot more simplistic than I had originally foreseen.